# Late 2011 MacBook Pro (macOS 10.13.1) won't boot after update

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, high-sierra

My MacBook Pro won't boot after updating the OS - it's just been saying that it's calculating the time remaining. Then, it shut down unexpectedly and when I try to boot it, it just shows the loading bar stuck at about a twentieth of the way with the Apple logo above it.

Is there anything I can do to continue using my MacBook normally without having to reinstall the OS losing all my data?

Comment: What happens if you try to boot in Safe Mode (hold shift)?  If you boot in [Verbose Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting overnight did the trick - just let it finish the update.

Answer (score 1):

I waited overnight but the machine did not boot fully and was stuck at the loading bar.

Just a few minutes back, I force shut the machine and rebooted. I was taken to the set-up (the one that usually comes up after the update) and I was done.

Checked the "About This Mac" by clicking at  to confirm if the update had been installed and it's confirmed.

Hope the above helps for those for whom waiting overnight didn't do the trick.